# Why are there letters in my correlation table in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pearson-correlation

[image]I've printed a correlation table on Pandas for some results derived from a questionnaire. There are some letters in the correlation values for some reason. Not sure what's causing this and how to solve it.

I was expecting normal numeric values. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking with respect to column "Agree with link to ED". -3.679900e-01 is scientific notation. It is the same as -3.6799 * 10^-1 i.e. -0.36799. Internally it will be treated as a number.

If you want more search up scientific notation.